# How to check how many inputs user entered in batch file?

Tags: batch-file

So iam trying to make a script that if the user enters "listproc 100" it displays tasklist and filters PID value by if its greater then or equal to 100,and if user enters 2 inputs e.g "listproc 100 500" it will do tasklist of PID values that are greater then or equal to 100 and also less then or equal to 500.However Iam using a goto,is there a way I can do this without having to ask the user if they have entered 1 or 2 inputs, and be able to make the script work it out on its own.So for exmaple if i entered "listproc 100 500" it would show result and not have to ask if i entered 1 or 2 inputs.

```
@echo off

set /p "input=1 or 2 inputs"

REM asks user how many inputs they entered

if "%input%" == "1" (
    goto one
)

if "%input%" == "2" (
    goto two
)

REM filters depending on number of inputs

:one
tasklist /FI "PID ge %1"

:two
tasklist /FI "PID ge %1" /FI "PID le %2"
```

Comment: You go into user query loop where you them for one input at a time, count the times around the loop until they enter quit or q or something. Another options is to get them all in one line entry and then process it in a loop. See `help for`.

Comment: "listproc 100 500" suggests you don't want to ask the user to interactively input the values, but call your script with parameters. See `call /?` for how to handle this.

Comment: [foolproof counting of arguments](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2836)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "part2=%2"
set "part1=%1"
if defined part1 (
 if defined part2 (
  tasklist /FI "PID ge %1" /FI "PID le %2"
 ) else (
  tasklist /FI "PID ge %1"
 )
) else ECHO Need at least one argument
pause
```

Assuming you want to execute `thisbatch 1234 5678` where `5678` is optional.

It would be possible to omit the assignments to `part?` and replace `if defined part?` with `if "%?" neq ""` (where `?` is `1` or `2`)

This is assuming that you can trust your users and they are going to enter according to expections (ie. not `thisbatch crash me`) - GIGO.

Or are you wanting to run this fully interactively?